# How to search for a string in a text file using Qt

Tags: qt, search, text, qstring

I'm trying to search for a string in a text file; my aim is to write it only if it isn't already written inside my text file.

Here's my function (I don't know how to put inside the while loop):

```
QFile MyFile("text.txt");
MyFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
QTextStream in (&MyFile);

while(!MyFile.atEnd())
  { //do something to search string inside }

MyFile.close();
```

How can I do that? From Qt's Help, method "contains" works with const variable only; can I use it to look for my string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
[..]
QString searchString("the string I am looking for");
[..]
QTextStream in (&MyFile);
QString line;
do {
    line = in.readLine();
    if (!line.contains(searchString, Qt::CaseSensitive)) {
        // do something
    }
} while (!line.isNull());
```

Comment: This will only work accurately if the searchString doesn't contain a new line character.

Comment: The commands used seem to be valid, but the program flow logic doesn't: You _do something_ for every line which does not contain the string. You should rather toggle a boolean value at the _do something_ point of your code, and break the loop. And then, check this bool outside the loop to conditionally _do something_.

Answer (score 5):

In case of not large file

```
QFile MyFile("text.txt");
MyFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
QTextStream in (&MyFile);
const QString content = in.readAll();
if( !content.contains( "String" ) {
//do something
}
MyFile.close();
```

To not repeat other answers in case of larger files do as vahancho suggested